# why i am getting this error ??GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error: `401 Unauthorized`

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am trying to implement Paypal Sandbox in my project. I have created a `trait` inside the `app` folder:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

trait ConsumesExternalServices
{
    public function makeRequest(
        $method,
        $requestUrl,
        $queryParams = [],
        $formParams = [],
        $headers = [],
        $isJsonRequest=false
    ) {
        $client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => $this->baseUri,
        ]);

        if (method_exists($this, 'resolveAuthorization')) {
            $this->resolveAuthorization($queryParams, $formParams, $headers);
        }

        $response = $client->request($method, $requestUrl, [
            $isJsonRequest ? 'json' : 'form_params' => $formParams,
            'headers' => $headers,
            'query' => $queryParams,
        ]);

        $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        if (method_exists($this, 'decodeResponse')) {
            $response = $this->decodeResponse($response);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

I have also created the Paypal Services:

```php
use App\Traits\ConsumesExternalServices;

class PaypalServices
{
    use ConsumesExternalServices;

    protected $baseUri;
    protected $clientId;
    protected $clientSecret;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->baseUri = config('services.paypal.base_uri');
        $this->clientId = config('services.paypal.client_id');
        $this->clientSecret = config('services.paypal.client_secret');
    }

    public function resolveAuthorization(&$queryParams, &$formParams, &$headers)
    {
        $headers['Authorization']=$this->resolveAccessToken();
    }

    public function decodeResponse($response)
    {
        return json_decode($response);
    }

    public function resolveAccessToken()
    {
        $credentials = base64_encode("{$this->clientId} : {$this->clientSecret}");
  
        return "Basic {$credentials}";
    }
}
```

I am trying to integrate my sandbox account with my project but whenever I use `tinker` and try to make a request, I get the following error:

```
Psy Shell v0.10.8 (PHP 7.4.15 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $paypal=new App\Services\PaypalServices;
=> App\Services\PaypalServices {#3473}
>>> $paypal->makeRequest('GET','v1/invoicing/invoices');

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException with message 'Client error: `GET https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"}
```

I have no idea what is the problem. Laravel version is 8 and I am using Paypal Malaysia account.

I have mentioned in `.env` file:

```
PAYPAL_BASE_URI=https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=
PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET=
```

Inside my `config/servies.php` file:

```php
'paypal' => [
    'base_uri' => env('PAYPAL_BASE_URI'),
    'client_id' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET')
],
```

Comment: It's failing because the credentials are wrong or not being sent correctly. What does your config file look like?

Comment: @Super_Simon will edit and show what my config/services.php file looks like

Comment: The response is pretty clear: "error":"**invalid_client**".... It is related to your `base_uri`, `client_id` and `client_secret`...

Comment: @matiaslauriti this is what i am trying to figure out . what i am doing wrong i used same client id in the paypal checkout and it was working fine but i have no clue what i am doing wrong here :(

Answer (score 0):

What client-id are you using? is it sandbox? If you use a live one with the base_uri set to sandbox, it will error with that 401.  You need a valid clientid+secret for the environment you're testing in, from your [REST apps](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications). If you still have issues, create a new REST app there and ensure you copy-paste from it correctly.

Comment: yes i am using sandbox and my base_uri is set to sand box PAYPAL_BASE_URI=https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com, and yes i was using the same client_id and secret which was generated by the app still i am getting this error

Comment: But is it a sandbox REST app client-id, you didn't answer what your client-id is